# Persist console with winrm and powershell

Tags: powershell, winrm

I just started working with powershell to automate a process, and now I'm stuck with win remoting.
I enabled remoting on the machine I want to connect to and can execute a singleline command easily, e.g.

```
winrs -r:http://$servername:5985 -u:$user "dir c:\"
```

And after that command is executed the remote shell is done and i need to write winrs -r... again everytime I need to execute a command.
Is there any way to stay in the remote computer's console, like when I'm telneting or connecting with ssh?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PowerShell try:

```
Enter-PSSession -ComputerName $servername
```

Comment: Wow! Works great :D I don't even need to send my credentials with this method. Thanks a lot for the quick response.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind, the session is destroyed once you exit the session (type Exit-PSSession or 'exit'). To keep it running and connect to it later on - create a session. Take a look at the help for the New-PSSession cmdlet.

Comment: Thanks again. Just one thing I noticed: When entering the wmi cli with wmic, winrs works better for me, since the session stays active.
Entering wmic in Enter-PSSession mode, does not allow me to work in the wmi cli.

Comment: I've never worked with wmic inside a remoting session but everything it can do the Get-WmiObject (and related wmi cmdlets) can do as well. Give it a try.